Merge tags for "IND-CCA" and "chosen-ciphertext-attack"?
At the moment we have the two tags ind-cca and chosen-ciphertext-attack.
However the tag ind-cpa is a synonym for chosen-plaintext-attack.
Should we merge ind-cca into chosen-ciphertext-attack as ind-cpa has been merged into chosen-plaintext-attack?

Based on the fact ind-cpa has indeed been merged as a synonym of chosen-ciphertext-attack, it seems rather logic to do the same with ind-cca and chosen-ciphertext-attack.
I´ve taken the freedom to add your suggestion so everyone can vote for it. (Maybe you could drop a line in the chat so others are aware their vote is needed too… no matter if they vote “pro” or “contra”).
Based on (let´s just call it) “popular demand”… done.

Everyone with 5+ answer score in that tag. Which is less than 10 active users. I think you should just make it happen if your moderator powers allow, since this seems like consensus.

@otus Where you‘re correct, you‘re correct. Consider it done.
